# Add a gap on either side of a CSS Grid to accommodate resized grid items and prevent wrapping

Tags: reactjs, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid that is 6x10 images. Grid items are resizable by changing their span values when they scroll into center. This causes the items in the last column to wrap and change the placement of the images. The issue is that the wrap is jarring and makes navigating or scrolling to the next image unpredictable because the images positions change.

I'm looking for a way to center justify grid items, with a gap on either side of the grid, while keeping to the 6x10 layout.

I have and am currently still trying to make this work by adding grid items to the photo array at the beginning and end of each row, and shrinking them when an image is resized.

One issue is that images can be either 1x1 or 1x2 depending on whether the image is portrait or landscape.

Below is a screenshot to show how the size differences can complicate things. Portrait images can push images below them to the next row, which is intentional. But I'd like to change the width of images and keep rows from wrapping.

I've also included some code to help explain how images are sized.

Thanks in advance for any help

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";


const PhotoGrid = (props) => {

  const sortPhotos = (a, b) => a.index - b.index;
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState(null)
  const [imgCount, setImgCount] = useState(0)
  const gridRef = useRef(null);
  const gridWrapperRef = useRef(null)
  const [imagesLoaded, setImagesLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [photoId, setPhotoId] = useState(null)

  const imgCounter = () => {
    setImgCount(imgCount + 1)
    console.log("images loaded", imgCount, props.photos.length, photos.length)
    if (imgCount + 1 === 60){
      setImagesLoaded(true)
      console.log("images loaded")
    }
  }
  
  const scrollPosition = () => {

    if (props.mobile){
    const grid = gridRef.current;
    const photos = grid.children
    const gridWrapper = gridWrapperRef.current;
    const gridWrapperRect = gridWrapper.getBoundingClientRect()
    const gridWrapperWidth = gridWrapperRect.width
    const height = gridWrapperRect.height
    
      for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {

      let photo = photos[i]; 
      const gridItem = photo.getBoundingClientRect();
      const top = Math.abs(gridItem.top)
      const left = Math.abs(gridItem.left)
      const centered = (top >= height * .25 && top < height * .4) && (left >= gridWrapperWidth * .3 && left <= gridWrapperWidth * .5)
    
      const findCenter = () => {
        if (centered && !!photo){
          return eval(photo.id)
        }
      }

      const centeredId = findCenter()

      const changeCells = (centeredId) => {
      if (!!centeredId){
        const centeredType = !!photos[centeredId].getElementsByClassName("tile").length
        const centeredOrientation = !!photos[centeredId].getElementsByClassName("portrait").length
        const first = Math.floor(centeredId/6) * 6
        const range = centeredOrientation ? 16 + first : 11 + first
   
        for (let i = first; i < range; i++){ 
          let rangePhoto = photos[i];
          const rangeOrientation = !!rangePhoto?.getElementsByClassName("portrait").length
          const rangeType = !!photos[i].getElementsByClassName("tile").length
          if (!!rangePhoto){

            if (!centeredType){   
                  
              if (eval(rangePhoto.id) === centeredId && photoId !== centeredId){
  
                setPhotoId(eval(rangePhoto.id))
              if (!rangeType){
                if (!rangeOrientation){
                  console.log("rangeType", rangeType, rangePhoto.firstChild, rangePhoto, rangePhoto.style)
                  rangePhoto.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 80`
                  rangePhoto.style.gridRowEnd = `span 80`
                  rangePhoto.firstChild.style.height = '220px'
                  rangePhoto.firstChild.style.width = '240px'
                  rangePhoto.firstChild.style.top = '50%'
                  setPhotoId(null)
                }
                else {
                  rangePhoto.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 80`
                  rangePhoto.style.gridRowEnd = `span 120`
                  rangePhoto.firstChild.style.height = '340px'
                  rangePhoto.firstChild.style.width = '240px'
                  rangePhoto.firstChild.style.top = '50%'
                  setPhotoId(null)
                }}
                else{
                  console.log("rangePhoto", rangePhoto.firstChild, rangePhoto, rangePhoto.style)
                  rangePhoto.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 1`
                  rangePhoto.style.gridRowEnd = `span 1`
                }
              }
              if (eval(rangePhoto.id) !== centeredId){
                if (!rangeOrientation){
                rangePhoto.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 32`
                rangePhoto.style.gridRowEnd = `span 40`
                rangePhoto.firstChild.style.height = '100px'
                rangePhoto.firstChild.style.top = '50%'
              }
              else {
                rangePhoto.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 32`
                rangePhoto.style.gridRowEnd = `span 80`
                rangePhoto.firstChild.style.height = '220px'
                rangePhoto.firstChild.style.top = '50%'
              }
            }
          }
          else{
              if (!rangeOrientation){
                rangePhoto.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 40`
                rangePhoto.style.gridRowEnd = `span 40`
                rangePhoto.firstChild.style.width = '120px'
                rangePhoto.firstChild.style.height = '100px'
              }
              else {
              rangePhoto.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 40`
              rangePhoto.style.gridRowEnd = `span 80`
              rangePhoto.firstChild.style.width = '120px'
              rangePhoto.firstChild.style.height = '220px'
              rangePhoto.firstChild.style.top = '50%'
              }
            }      
          }
        }

        return [first, range]
      }
    }

const rowState = changeCells(centeredId)


const reset = () => { 
  for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
    let photo = photos[i]; 
    const orientation = !!photo.getElementsByClassName("portrait").length
    const type = !!photo.getElementsByClassName("tile").length

  if (!!rowState){
    if((eval(photo.id) > rowState[1]) || (eval(photo.id) < rowState[0])){
    if (!orientation){
      photo.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 40`
      photo.style.gridRowEnd = `span 40`
      photo.firstChild.style.height = '100px'
      photo.firstChild.style.width = '120px'
    }
    else {
      photo.style.gridColumnEnd = `span 40`
      photo.style.gridRowEnd = `span 80`
      photo.firstChild.style.height = '220px'
      photo.firstChild.style.width = '120px'
    }
  }}


}}
reset(rowState)

    }
  }
}



useEffect(() => {
  const grid = gridRef.current;
  const gridWrapper = document.getElementById("grid-wrapper");
  const gridRect = grid?.getBoundingClientRect() 
  if (!!gridRect){  
    const center = gridRect.width/2
    gridWrapper.scrollLeft = center
  }
}, [!!gridRef.current === true])


useEffect(() => {    
  !!props.photos && setPhotos([...props.photos])
  }, [props.photos])




  return (
    <article >
        <>
          <div 
          id="grid-wrapper"
          className="grid-wrapper"
          onScroll={() => scrollPosition()}
          ref={gridWrapperRef}
          >
            <Grid
              ref={gridRef}
              className="grid"
              style={{ opacity: imagesLoaded ? 1 : 0 }}
              >

              {!!photos && !photos !== !null && photos !== undefined && photos.sort(sortPhotos).map((photo) => (
              <GridItem
                    className="grid-item"
                    id={photo.index}
                    mobile={props.mobile}
                    edit={props.edit}
                    key={photo.index}
                    orientation={photo.orientation}
                    url={!!photo.url}
                    photo={photo}
                    collaborator={!!photo.u_id && props.folderCollaborators.filter(user => user.uuid === photo.u_id)}
                    colorArr={props.colorArr}
                    highlight={photo.color}
                  >
                    <PictureFrame
                    className={!!photo.url ? photo.orientation ? "picture landscape" : "picture portrait" : 'tile landscape'}
                      mobile={props.mobile}
                      url={photo.url}
                      highlight={photo.color}
                      contentSizing={!!photo.name || !!photo.details}
                      enableDelete={props.enableDelete}
                      orientation={photo.orientation}
                      >  

                      <img
                        className={"photo"}
                        onLoad={() => imgCounter() }
                        src={
                          !!photo.thumbnail_url
                          ? photo.url
                          : require('../assets/100x135.png')
                        }
                        />

                    </PictureFrame>
                  </GridItem>
                ))}
            </Grid>
          </div>
      </>
      </article>
  );
};
export default PhotoGrid;


const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1px;
  background: black;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(241, minmax(1px, 1px)) ;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;

  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    padding-block-start: 20vh;
    padding-block-end: 40vh;
    padding-inline: 40vw;
  };
  .grid-item {
    position: relative;
    grid-row-end: span 40;
    grid-column-end: span 40;
    };
`
const GridItem = styled.div`
z-index: ${({url}) => url ? "1" : "-5"};
`       
const PictureFrame = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: ${({orientation}) => orientation ? '50%' : '100%' };
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: ${({orientation}) => orientation ? '100px' : '220px'};
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 13px;
    width: 120px ;
    max-width: calc(100% - 15px);
    transition: 
    height .1s ease-in,
    width .1s ease-in,
    border-radius .2s ease-out, 
    background-color 0s linear 1s, 
    max-width .3s ease-out .2s, 
    padding-right .2s ease-out .1s, 
    padding-left .2s ease-out .1s, 
    padding-block .2s ease-out .1s, 
    ${({url}) => url ? 'box-shadow .2s ease-in .6s' : 'box-shadow .3s ease-in'};

  .photo {
    max-height: 110%;
}
`
```

Comment: can you share your whole code that i can check.

Comment: @BobMartin Sorry for the late response, holidays, work and trying other approaches before I come back. I updated my post to include more code. In this iteration I'm shrinking the surrounding grid items to accommodate the enlarged image.